# Multiple Apache Rewrite Rules depending on domain plus rewriteCond within another rewriteCond

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Good day, please help me i have been struggling with this "simple" rewriteCond this is my original code:

```
######################################################################## Willowvine
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^willowvine\.dev$

RewriteRule . - [S=1]

RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admininistration/$1 [QSA,L]
######################################################################## EndRules

######################################################################## Dove Rules
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dove\.dev$

RewriteRule . - [S=2]

RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin_another/$1 [QSA,L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /client/recruiter/4021/$1 [QSA,L]
######################################################################## End Dove Rules
```

I keep getting this error:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable
>   configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the
>   limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

basically what i want to do is to do this:

```
if ${HTTP_HOST} == 'willowvine.dev/'    rewriterule 1: admin/* goes to
administration/*   else if ${HTTP_HOST} == 'dove.dev'    rewriterule
1:  admin/* goes to admin_another      rewriterule 2: if((${HTTP_HOST}
+ ${HTTP_URI}) != 'dove.dev/admin') root folder must start from /path/to/folder/start/he
```

Comment: Looks like you have an empty line between `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`. Remove those empty lines, they break your configuration.

Comment: I have changed it to this:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^willowvine\.dev$
RewriteRule . - [S=1]
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ administration/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dove\.dev$
RewriteRule . - [S=2]
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin_recruiter/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /client/recruiter/4021/$1 [QSA,L]

But now when I go to willowvine.dev it takes me to the "/client/recruiter/4021/" folder and when i go to the willowvine.dev/admin/ it takes me to the correct one, but dove.dev for both rules gives me an internal 500 error again.

Comment: @arkascha that's nonsense. Actually the final two RewriteRule lines are joined which would break the configuration but I presume that's just a copy and paste error.

Comment: @cashmire please try formatting the final part of your question for readability. You chould also explain your use of the [S] (skip) flag; it would appear to do the opposite of what you want.

Comment: @noodl there is no flag in apache that allows you to group multiple rules depending on domain, [S] says that if {HTTP_HOST} != dove.dev [S]kip the next couple [S=2] (2) lines.

Comment: @noodl what i want is that if current domain is 'dove.dev' i want to run only two lines and if its not, apache must skip those rules.

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional condition to your 2nd rule to prevent the `^(.*)$` from looping. You can actually consolidate instead of using the `S` flags to skip around:

```
######################################################################## Willowvine
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^willowvine\.dev$
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admininistration/$1 [QSA,L]
######################################################################## EndRules

######################################################################## Dove Rules
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dove\.dev$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/client/recruiter
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /client/recruiter/4021/$1 [QSA,L]
######################################################################## End Dove Rules
```

Or just keeping to your original:

```
######################################################################## Willowvine
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^willowvine\.dev$

RewriteRule . - [S=1]

RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admininistration/$1 [QSA,L]
######################################################################## EndRules

######################################################################## Dove Rules
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dove\.dev$

RewriteRule . - [S=2]

RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin_another/$1 [QSA,L] 


### add conditions here for URIs that you don't want the rule to get applied to
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin_recruiter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/client/recruiter
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /client/recruiter/4021/$1 [QSA,L]
######################################################################## End Dove Rules
```

Comment: I am still getting a 500 error: what i want is that if current domain is 'dove.dev' i want to run only two lines and if its not, apache must skip those rules. But the thing is that I will have multiple domains setup like this in this single .htaccess file.

Comment: This workks:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^willowvine\.dev$
RewriteRule . - [S=1]
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admininistration/$1 [QSA,L]
######################################################################## EndRules

######################################################################## Dove Rules
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dove\.dev$
RewriteRule . - [S=1]
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin_recruiter/$1 [QSA,L] 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /client/recruiter/4021/$1 [QSA,L]
######################################################################## End Dove

Comment: so the problem is with this line: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /client/recruiter/4021/$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: @cashmire that's what I said, the `^(.*)$` regex is causing the loop, so you need a condition so that URI's that already start with `/client/recruiter/` **won't** get rewritten *again*. The condition in my answer before it prevents that.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me @jon Lin, but I changed it to this and still not working gives me a 500 error:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^willowvine\.dev$
RewriteRule . - [S=1]
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admininistration/$1 [QSA,L]
########################################################################
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dove\.dev$
RewriteRule . - [S=2]
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin_another/$1 [QSA,L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin_recruiter
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /client/recruiter/4021/$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: @cashmire you want `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/client/recruiter`, **not** `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin_recruiter`

Comment: if I do that it takes me to the root file and not the file in "/client/recruiter/4021/" folder though. I am trying something else as well this::: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dove\.dev$
RewriteRule . - [S=2]
RewriteRule  ^admin/(.*)$  admin_recruiter/$1    [QSA,L]
RewriteRule  ^client/(.*)$  client/recruiter/4021/$1  [QSA,L]

Comment: @cashmire I don't know what you're talking about. The rules work fine for me in a blank htaccess file. As in my answer, the condition checks that the URI *doesn't already start with* `/client/recruiter` before applying the rule that rerwite *anything* to `/client/recuirter/4021/$1`. Your other attempt will still loop. Your regular expression matches the target, that means it will loop unless you make a condition like I have in my answer

Comment: alright @jon Lin, the redirects works for for dove.dev/ and it goes to "/client/recruiter/4021" thanks that was my mistake, but now it does not redirect dove.dev/admin/ to dove.dev/admin_recruiter/ i get this error: file not found: The requested URL /client/recruiter/4021/admin_recruiter/ was not found on this server.

Comment: @cashmire if you don't want it to be applied to `/admin_recruiter` then just add that condition that you had before (e.g. use both conditions)

Comment: erm, i dont get it, sorry for being a bit slow, what condition did i have before because i tried this and still not really working:

RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin_recruiter/$1 [QSA,L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/client/recruiter
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /client/recruiter/4021/$1 [QSA,L]